# "reduce" a set of rows in Hive to another set of rows

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I'm using Hive for batch-processing of my spatial database. My trace table looks something like this:

```
object | lat  | long  | timestamp

1      | X11  | X12   | T11

1      | X21  | X22   | T12

2      | X11  | X12   | T21

1      | X31  | X22   | T13

2      | X21  | X22   | T22
```

I want to map each lat long of each object to a number (think about map-matching for example), but the algorithm needs to consider a number of adjacent data points to get the result. For example, I need all 3 data points of object 1 to map each of those 3 data points to a number. Can't process them one by one.

I'm thinking of using map-reduce with hive using transform, but I'm not sure how to this. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: How do you calculate the result of the 3 data points? what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: The result of 3 data points will be something like this:

    1 | X11 | X12 | T11 | Y11

    1 | X21 | X22 | T12 | Y12

    1 | X31 | X31 | T13 | Y13

Comment: what are the Y s here and what does | mean ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom map reduce functionality in Hive.

With the following:

```
add file /some/path/identity.pl;
add file /some/path/collect.pl;

from (
  from trace_input
  MAP id, lat, lon, ts
  USING './identity.pl'
  as id, lat, lon, ts
 CLUSTER BY id) map_output
REDUCE id, lat, lon, ts
USING './collect.pl' as id, list
```

**trace_input** contains your trace data as described above:

```
create table trace_input(id string, lat string, lon string, ts string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t'
stored as textfile ;
```

**identity.pl** is a simple script to dump out each line (could also be a script to select just the lat, long fields):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<STDIN>) {
    print;
}
```

**collect.pl** (sample [here](https://gist.github.com/libjack/5591845)) is simple script which collects consecutive lines with the same object id, saves the remainder of each line, and dumps out a line with id and comma separated list (tab separator).

The **cluster by** clause will assure the reducers get the correctly sorted input needed by the collect script.

The output of the user scripts are tab separated *STRING* columns.

Running the query, will result in the following output:

```
1       X11,X12,T11,X21,X22,T12,X31,X22,T13
2       X11,X12,T21,X21,X22,T22
```

You can modify the map script to limit the columns, and/or modify the reduce script to add results or separate the lat, lon from the ts, etc.

If this form is sufficient, you could insert directly into a result table by adding an *insert* before the reduce:

```
from (
  from trace_input
  MAP id, lat, lon, ts
  USING './identity.pl'
  as id, lat, lon, ts
 CLUSTER BY id) map_output
INSERT overwrite table trace_res
REDUCE id, lat, lon, ts
USING './collect.pl';
```

The fields will be converted from string fields to match the schema of trace_res as necessary.

If you use collection types like I do, you can also do something like:

```
create table trace_res as
select sq.id, split(sq.list,",") from
(
from (
  from trace_input
  MAP id, lat, lon, ts
  USING './identity.pl'
  as id, lat, lon, ts
 CLUSTER BY id) map_output
REDUCE id, lat, lon, ts
USING './collect.pl' as (id int, list string)
) sq;
```

This second field in the created table will be a list of all the lat, lon, ts; but probably will have a more complex table than that.